# Range-based for over pair list

Tags: c++, c++11

Say, I want to iterate a number of pairs defined inline. Is there a shorter way to write:

```
for(auto pair : std::initializer_list<std::pair<int,int>>{{1,2}, {3,4}})
    // ...
```

?

Comment: You can alias that type :)

Comment: @StoryTeller That's not shorter, is it?

Comment: The loop expression is shorter. Which will reduce stuff significantly if you do this looping more than once.

Comment: I won't, though. What works is putting it outside with `int list[][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};` but I would prefer an inline solution - if available

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just specify the first element is a pair. The rest will be deduced automatically:

```
for(auto& pair : {std::pair<int,int>{1,2}, {3,4}})
  ;
```

The braced enclosed initializer is deduced to be `std::initalizer_list`, and the first element being named a pair will require *all* elements to be an initalizer for a pair.

You tagged C++11, but for completeness, it can be even shorter in C++17:

```
for(auto& pair : {std::pair{1,2}, {3,4}})
  ;
```

Due to class template argument deduction. If you don't have that, than `std::make_pair` will do if you want to maintain the benefits of template argument deduction:

```
for(auto& pair : {std::make_pair(1,2), {3,4}})
  ;
```

Though ostensibly, it isn't as useful for code golfing as the C++17 version.

Comment: Nice one, thanks :) Based on your answer, I also found this version that works below C++17: `for(auto pair : {std::make_pair(1,2),{3,4},{5,6}})`

Comment: @IceFire - Yeah, it works in C++11 too. The argument deduction can replace `make_pair` in C++17 however.

Comment: Yes, I like this best. My compiler does not accept it so far, though. Anyways, we seem to have covered all options

Comment: Would you want to capture the pairs by reference instead of value? On most platforms shouldn't two ints and a pointer both be 8-bytes, but the ints are one less layer of indirection? I guess I'd hope that both generate the same assembly after the optimizer ran...

Comment: @RyanP - The initializer list content is immutable anyway, so if the OP intends to modify anything they'd need to operate on a copy either way. And if they don't, I feel your concerns are in the realm of premature optimization.

Answer (score 3):

The good ol' type alias:

```
using pairlist = std::initializer_list<std::pair<int,int>>;

for(auto pair : pairlist{{1,2}, {3,4}})
{
    // stuff happens here
}
```

Comment: this is actually longer

Comment: @IceFire Not on average over more than one loop.

Comment: I have said nothing about multiple loops. In fact, wanting to put this list inline is a clear indicator that I have only one loop instance

Comment: @IceFire Asking this question here, however, had created more typing than any possible shortening in the source.  So bothering to ask this question is a clear indicator that there is more than one loop instance.

Comment: @Yakk Not with the same content right to the colon... The question was "I want something shorter", you provided something longer, which is not what I asked for. I will not add anything else to the discussion.

Comment: @IceFire But your question is relevant to future readers and their specific needs may differ from yours.

Comment: This is a bit more concise and easier to understand coming from other languages I would argue. The higher rated solutions are more terse but also don't compile for me (MSVC).